# Does SQL Server create a log entry when an exception occurs in a Trigger?

Tags: sql-server, logging, triggers, rdbms, ldf

My understanding is that when a Trigger fails then the entire transaction rolls back. Assuming this is correct does SQL server log these failures anywhere?

Would they be logged in the .ldf file? or are only successful transactions logged there?

Comment: Yes when an unhandled exception occurs inside a trigger it will rollback the implicit transaction. Not really sure what you are trying to accomplish here though.

Comment: I want to see the SQL statements that failed due to the trigger failing? So I can potentially re-run them.

Comment: I had a feeling that was what you are after. You can't just read that from the log file. That isn't how logging works. You should add error handling to your trigger so you can handle errors.

Comment: OK thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my development environment I was able to retrieve the aborted transactions using the [ApexSQL](https://www.apexsql.com/sql-tools-log.aspx) transaction log reader.